# Complex push notification query

Tags: parse-platform

I've been playing with Parse for a while and It's pretty neat! Sadly I just encountered an issue that I can't seem to get resolved.

As soon as an object ("Alert") is saved to my database I would like to send a push notification. The object saved contains a field called neighbourhoodName which is a string. I would like to send everyone a push notification subscribed to this neighberhoudName. (This ain't the problem, hold on! :-P).

My Alert object also holds a GeoPoint and I would like to send every user in a specific radius a push notification. As you might figure a user could be subscribed to a neighbourhood (for example 'Hellas') and also be currently in the neighbourhood of 'Hellas'. This means he/she will receive two notifications.. this is not what I want.

So I thought; lets use Parse.Query.or. Send a push notification if the user is subscribed to the correct channel OR is in the current radius of the Alert. Sadly, Parse.Query.or can't be used with GeoPoints.

How can I tackle this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found there to be some issues when using [query whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles:]. Using [query withinGeobox:] is much more flexible.

Comment: Problem still persists I think... Parse.Query can't be used with GeoPoints and nearGeoPoint is still a GeoPoint..

Comment: @Mittchel sorry the delay. Did you figure this out? I'm doing push targeting with a geopoint query, but I'm doing it iOS client side. So that may be why my suggestion didn't help. If you found a solution, I'd love to hear it for future reference.